# Why can I compile 64 bit Delphi libraries through runtime package but not through source?

Tags: delphi

We are just starting on migrating some of our projects to 64-bit in Delphi, we also have a couple of 3rd party Delphi libraries that we are using. 
Traditionally, when we use a 3rd party library we do so by using the design time package .bpl OR we just have the compiler compile the source code.

However, in 64-bit it seems we have to do it completely differently. If we are compiling a 64-bit library we need to use DCU.

For example, we have a library that we needed to use in 64-bit. The library supports 64-bit. To get it to work, I had to compile the runtime package as 64-bit then point the compiler to the outputted 64-bit DCU files. When I try to compile the library from source as 64-bit we get all kinds of errors.

So my question basically is: Why/How can we compile the source code through the runtime packages in 64-bit just fine, but when we try to compile as just source code in 64-bit we get errors?

To further illustrate just in case that wasn't clear:

A. Put all source files on search path. Compile program as 64-bit. ERRORS.

B. Open up supplied runtime .dproj from 3rd party library. Compile runtime library as 64-bit. Put outputted 64-bit DCU on search path. Compile program. Works fine.

Thanks

Edit: I'm going to be much more specific because it appears that i have failed in conveying what I'm trying to ask here.

We are using Clever Internet Suite 9.1 for Delphi.
We DO NOT use the design time package when compiling in 32-bit. We link directly to the source code through Delphi's search path. This works fine.

When I change my application to build as 64-bit We get this error:

> [dcc64 Error] clSocket.pas(1971): E2089 Invalid typecast

A sample of the offending code (Slightly changed):

```
procedure cldostuff.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = cl_const)
    and (clSpecialType(Message).LookupHandle = FLookupHandle) then
  begin
    syncerror:= clSpecialType(Message).syncerror;
    SetEvent(FCompleted);
  end;
end;
```

The error is on the casting of the TMessage. I understand why TMessage would cause an error. I am not concerned about the error. 
I am curious as to HOW compiling through a "package" works but not in DCU. Apparently I have misused the terminology of "Runtime package". I will post exactly what the clever developers told me on how to use in 64 bit.

> The Clever Internet Suite fully supports 64-bit platform. The installer includes binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit. Also, if you want to re-compile the library, you need to switch the platform option within the clinetsuite_x.dproj file, and recompile it (where _x depends on your Delphi version, e.g., in case of Delphi 10.3 Rio, the project file will be clinetsuite_103.dproj).

So I do Exactly that. I open up that .Dproj file and compile it. Once I do that it creates a Win64/Output folder that has ALL the dcus of the library. I can link to that and work in win64 bit just fine.

My questions is WHY does it work when I compile through the "Supplied .dproj file" but not when I compile through source code.

Hopefully I've done a better job of articulating what I am asking.

Comment: There is no such thing as *compile the source from runtime packages*. Runtime packages contain compiled, executable code (like a DLL), and nothing from them is compiled into your application except a reference to the code in the package. The part that is compiled into your application is taken from somewhere other than the package, which may be the .dcu or .dcp file. There is no issue with compiling a 64-bit application to use 64-bit packages. Compile a 64-bit version of the package, and then compile the app that uses it as 64-bit.

Comment: @KenWhite I am not using design time packages in 64 bit. I am using no "Packages" in 64 bit. I am linking to dcu compiled from the runtime package. Let me see if I can explain a bit more clearly.

We have a library that we also have the source code to. When I make my application 64 bit and link to just the .pas files I get errors like: Invalid Typecast 
I Don't get these errors when I compile as 32 bit.

Comment: A works for me. What are you doing differently?

Comment: The library developers provided a .dproj that creates a runtime package that compiles them as 64 bit and outputs dcus. I can use these dcus in 64 bit but I can't use the source code in 32 bit. My question is why is that the case. Hopefully thats a bit more clear.

Comment: I think I overwrote my previous comment. But I am NOT using design packages. I am aware that design packages won't work in 64 bit.

Basically like I said above. I can use DCU that are compiled from a runtime package .dproj provided by library creators. If I try to compile from source as 64 bit I get stuff like Invalid Typecast errors

Comment: I may be incorrect in using the term runtime package. Basically, the library provides us with 2 .dproj files. One is for what I'm calling "runtime package" and when I do a build/compile on that it outputs DCUS to a win64/output folder. The other is the Design time package. When I build that i have the option of right clicking > Install and it puts the outputted .bpl file into embarcaderos default search path. 

I was under the impression that the first one was the runtime package but I may be mistaken.

Comment: I have no problem compiling from source in 64 bit. What are you doing differently?

Comment: Maybe there are some symbols defined with `{$DEFINE ...}` in the `.dproj` file of the library for conditional compilation of the source files of the library..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Like i've said. I'm doing nothing differently.

Comment: @GWimpassinger Thanks. I had thought of that. When I open up the .drpoj and do a view project source there is some compiler definitions but none of them are Define. They are stuff like {$LONGSTRINGS ON}, etc. So I don't see anywhere that anything is being conditionally defined

Comment: So how come it works fine for me but not you? Clearly you are doing something wrong. But we have no details. How can we reproduce? Why can't we see error messages? A [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't know how to answer that. I've told you what I'm doing. Nothing is different that I know of. Asking me the same question repeatedly is not helping. Are you using the Clever library because you keep saying that "It" works for you, even before I told you what library i'm using. If you are then that is interesting and I could learn something from this. If you're not then you're contributing nothing.
Ive edited my original post with the exact issue with all information that I have.

Comment: "I am linking to dcu compiled from the runtime package" makes no sense. I guess you mean you are compiling the .pas files that are mentioned in the "contains" part of a package project. In that case, you should be able to link to the 64 bit package too. Just be sure it is accessible and to save your sanity, give it a proper suffix, so it won't be confused with a 32 bit package of the same name,

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes sorry I belive I've been using some terminology incorrectly. When I open up that clinetsuite_x.dproj and compile that, it outputs the DCUs for the entire library and that is what I'm linking to. When I do this its not outputting a package anywhere it just outputs the dcus

Comment: Well the edt helps. Compiler error is helpful. The issue will be compiler options. That code probably needs `{A+}` where the type `clSpecialType` is defined. It will pick it up from the package dproj file but not you lr code's dproj file. Really the compiler options should be enforced by a library include file that all files in library include. But this library is probably sloppy in that regard.

Comment: The reason I asked you what you were doing differently from me was to highlight the lack of detail in your original post. Just as you had no idea what the rest of us were doing when successfully compiling code, we had no idea what code you were compiling, with what options.

Comment: If you add the same .pas files to am´n executable project, it should work just as well. It is not entirely clear what you are doing, perhaps because you use certain wrong terminology. Generally things don't work because you have a bad or wrong library path or search path setting or because you are using the wrong files or have different settings for directives, etc. Hard to tell why it fails in your case.

Comment: A package project **should** output a package (*.bpl* and associated *.dcp*) **somewhere**. The main source file should be a *.dpk* file and have *requires* and *contains* sections. If not, you are not compiling a package.

Comment: @rudy not if the compiler options are provided by the dproj file of the two projects and they differ

Comment: @david: yes, of course, that is correct. Is indeed one of the possible reasons why they don't compile when used directly. That are the "different settings for directives, etc." I meant. I could have been a little clearer there.

Comment: Rudy and David and anyone else who answered this apologies to both of you because I've been using wrong terminology and I was also completely wrong about something I said. This is in fact a runtime library. It outputs a .BPL file into embarcadero/19/bpl/win64 I just didn't see it. So I know I said it didnt but I was very wrong there, apologies.

We do not use runtime packages here so I can't really use it anyways. But it is actually a runtime package :)

Comment: FWIW, this means that the library probably did not set any relevant settings in the .pas files. This should have been made easier and less dependent on exterior settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That compiler error is typically caused by a typecast between two value types of different size. If the code works in some compilation scenarios but not others then the obvious conclusion is that the record alignment options differ in those scenarios.

Most likely the package dproj file defines aligned records, i.e. `{$ALIGN ON}`. But your project does not. Perhaps it uses packed alignment, `{$ALIGN 1}`.

Make sure that all the units in the library are compiled with the same options as specified in the package dproj file. Typically that is done by the library providing an include file that specifies desired options and then the include file is included in all units. That insulates the code from compiler options specified in the host dproj file that are incompatible with those that the code requires.

You can add such a common include file since you have the source. In the longer term you should ask the developers of the library to make their code standalone and not require external specification of critical compiler options.

Comment: I would write "probably" instead of "typically", but otherwise, agreed.

Comment: The dproj source does have this in there:

{$ALIGN 8}

I don't want to post to much from their source code because I don't want to violate any licenses or anything. But they do also have a .inc file that lives with the .pas files that I link to. 

So would I need to put that {$ALIGN 8} somewhere in the .inc file or .pas files?

Comment: @rudy No, my use of typically is intentional. The idiom is used to suggest the most common practise of libraries. Probably would be used when talking about this specific one.

Comment: I'd expect to see the alignment specified in the inc file since it is critical to the meaning of much code.

Comment: Thanks for the help david. I added {$ALIGN 8} to the right spot in the .inc and everything worked :). Thanks you!

Comment: @D.D: {$ALIGN 8} is also the default for Win32 and Win64. But if there is not an include file that is included by (almost) every source file, then the settings in the project options (in the IDE and dproj) will be used. Take a look there.